# How to parse this json array?

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I have a php file that output json array:

```
[{"id":407,"parentId":406,"level":null,"name":"Зал VIII"},{"id":408,"parentId":406,"level":null,"name":"Зал IV"},]
```

Trying this function:

```
var levels = '';
function parse() {
    $.get('url_to_json_file', function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            levels += (value.id +' - '+ value.name);
        });
    });
return levels;
}
```

But result always `undefined - undefined`.

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/GP2S5/

Comment: You are returning the variable before AJAX is complete.

Comment: @undefined I would agree, but then why would he be getting `undefined - undefined`? he should be getting `""` :)

Comment: @KevinB Yes, you are right :), I didn't notice that.

Comment: try using JSON.parse() since you are using a regular .get and not .getJSON

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has a `$.parseJSON()` function.

Try:

```
$.parseJSON('[{"id":407,"parentId":406,"level":null,"name":"Зал VIII"},{"id":408,"parentId":406,"level":null,"name":"Зал IV"}]');
//Returns [Object,Object];
```